# What's the subject of this sentence?

Tags: subjects

> When it hatches has a broad face and a long flat tail.

I saw the sentence above on Internet, but it makes no sense to me.

What is the subject of that sentence?

Comment: Don't believe in all that you read on the Internet. Oh, wait...

Comment: Too Localised. This "sentence" is not in fact a sentence anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't call this localized. There is not specific jargon or regional dialect being used here. However, the sentence *is* ungrammatical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think they accidentally left out a word:

> When it hatches, **it** has a broad face and a long flat tail.

[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=efE3Ag00MpAC&pg=PT483&lpg=PT483&dq=%22when%20it%20hatches%20has%20a%20broad%20face%20and%20a%20long%20flat%20tail%22&source=bl&ots=l4wqaCtzfH&sig=GRMKgN-oi8l9nHMw_g8NtaHnHZE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYuZ653bXOAhUsB8AKHSRyBvcQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=%22when%20it%20hatches%20has%20a%20broad%20face%20and%20a%20long%20flat%20tail%22&f=false) (*What Your First Grader Needs to Know : Fundamentals of a Good First-Grade Education*)